# "Bringing my Java application to Mac OS X": Menus

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to make my Java applications integrate better with Mac OSX, and I have made it so that the menu will go to top of the screen. However, I am trying to manage the Quit and About menu items in the *premade* Application menu, using the following page: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac2/

However, when I try to make a class `extends Application` in Eclipse (On my Windows computer) I receive an error and the only option is to create the class, no imports available. Anybody know why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class Application is only available on Mac OS X, so you cannot extend from it on Windows. Have a look at [OSXAdapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000685-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) which shows a way to integrate the functionality using Reflection only and thus working on Mac OS X and at least compiling on other systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. OSXAdapter seems to be my best bet - it is much easier to write the whole program on my Windows 7 computer (for now)!